# Show mouse x11vnc server

Tags: vnc

I've been trying to get a view-only VNC connection to my phone with VNC Viewer app for iPhone, and I would like it to display the mouse connected to the raspberry pi.

On the raspberry pi, I'm using x11vnc so I can see the current display. I'm trying to create a google-glass like thing, so maybe you can see another solution.

The way I'm using this is like so:
raspberry pi -> x11vnc -> iphone 4
I'm using a wii remote as a mouse, and a wireless keyboard connected through bluetooth to the iphone. I need to be able to see where the mouse is on the phone.

Comment: Isn't screen mirroring closer to what you want to achieve?

Comment: @bex yeah. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get where VNC comes into this, and reading your question again, I don't really understand what devices output you what to display on what device. Maybe a diagram of some sort would help clarify the question?

Comment: @Bex Edited question for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Not completely clear on what you're asking for, but there's a full tutorial here that may give you what you want:
http://log.liminastudio.com/writing/tutorials/remote-desktop-control-of-a-raspberry-pi

Comment: In keeping with [our policy regarding informationless link-only answers](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/842/5538), if this post is not edited to contain information that can stand as an answer, however minimal, in 48 hours it will be converted to Community Wiki to simplify having it corrected by the community.